# Error building player (CommandInvokationFailure) Unity Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to setup Unity to building android games but now I'm stuck and I get this `error` once I try to `Build` & `Run`:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[

]
stdout[

]
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String[] progress_strings, Single progress_value, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.CompileResources (System.String stagingArea, System.String packageName, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidLibraries androidLibraries)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcessInternal (System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

I've been trying to Google my problem but it seems like all the answers are outdated because of new Android Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

> I've been trying to Google my problem but it seems like all the
>   answers are outdated because of new Android Studio ?

The solution to this problem changes each time a new SDK or SDK Build Tool is released.

> C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\ **24.0.0**
>   \aapt.exe

The current solution is to **delete** Android SDK Build Tool **REV.24** from the SDK Manager. This should solve your problem.

Comment: I ran into it last week too. I'm new to unity, is it common to have the tool compatibilities get out of sync like this?

Comment: @2manyprojects Yes, but you can prevent that by not using the latest Android API or Android SDK Build Tool or by not updating Andorid SDK at-all. The worst is the Xcode. Almost each update kills Unity but Unity always release an update for a fix after a week or two. They don't seem to care enough about fixing the Android version.